# An Example of a composite function that does not exist

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let's say $f(x)$, and $g(x)$ are two completely defined functions.

My understanding of composition's existence is that the domain of $g(x)$ must be a subset of the domain of $f(g(x))$, is that correct?

If yes, what two functions I can think of that will result in a composition that does not exist?

Thank you.

Comment: you need that the image of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$ otherwise $f\circ g$ will not be defined on all of $dom(g)$ but on the subset $f^{-1}(img(g))$

Comment: Consider $g,f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=-1$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. The domain of $g(x)$ equals the domain of $f(x)$ but $f(g(x))=f(-1)$ DNE since $-1$ isn't in the positive reals.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The complete description of a function $f$ contains its *domain* $A = \operatorname{dom} f$ and its *codomain* $B = \operatorname{codom} f$ which are two sets. Therefore we should always write $f : A \to B$ instead of $f(x)$. The latter is inadequate because it does not make precise for which $x$ the function is defined and in which set its values $f(x)$ are supposed to lie.

In some cases it may be acceptable to write simply $f(x)$, for example if we exclusively deal with functions having $\mathbb R$ as domain and codomain. In such cases it is automatically clear what $\operatorname{dom} f$ and $\operatorname{codom} f$ are.

Note that we must not confuse $\operatorname{codom} f$ with its *image* $\operatorname{im} f = f(A) = \{ f(a) \mid a \in A \} \subset B$; we may have $\operatorname{im} f \subsetneqq B$.

The codomain of a function is frequently also called its *range*.

The standard definition of the composition of functions $f : A \to B$ and $g: B '\to C$ requires $B = B'$. Then we get
$$g \circ f : A \to C, (g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) . \tag{1}$$

We can obviously extend this definition to the case that $B \subset B'$ or, even more generally, to the case that
$$\operatorname{im} f \subset B' \tag{2} .$$

> My understanding of composition's existence is that the domain of $g(x)$ must be a subset of the domain of $f(g(x))$, is that correct?

No. First of all we do not know the domain of $g(f(x))$ *before* we have a definition of the composite function. However, it is clear that the domain of $g(f(x))$, whatever its definition may be, must be subset of the domain of $f$; otherwise $f(x)$ would not be defined. But even if we would know the domain $A' \subset A$ of $g(f(x))$, this set has nothing to do with the domain $B'$ of $g$. Look at $(1)$ and $(2)$.

We can also define the composite function for *any two functions* $f : A \to B$ and $g: B '\to C$ via
$$g \circ f : f^{-1}(B \cap B') \to C, (g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) . \tag{3}$$
This works because for $x \in f^{-1}(B \cap B')$ we have $f(x) \in B \cap B' \subset B'$ so that we can use $f(x)$ as input for $g$.

This definition may lead to $\operatorname{dom} (g \circ f) = \emptyset$ which is completely uninteresting.